# How to reuse matching patterns in match clauses?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.match

I need to match two kinds of tuples and produce maps from them.

Both have a keyword and a string. One can have a third item (a language code).

```
[<key> <value>]        ~> {:type <key> :value <value>}
[<key> <value> <lang>] ~> {:type <key> :value <value> :lang <lang>}
```

I only need to match those which keyword is either `:foo` or `:bar` and decided that I would use [`clojure.core.match`](https://github.com/clojure/core.match):

```clj
(ns so.example
  (:require
   [clojure.core.match :refer [match]]))

(defn example-1 [ast]
  (let [l10n-key #{:foo :bar}]
    (match ast
      [(k :guard l10n-key) v lang] {:type k :value v :lang lang}
      [(k :guard l10n-key) v]      {:type k :value v})))

(example-1 [:foo 10])
;=> {:type :foo, :value 10}

(example-1 [:bar 20 "en"])
;=> {:type :bar, :value 20, :lang "en"}
```

That works but I wanted to reuse the matching pattern `:guard l10n-key` in different clauses. So I thought I could use some syntax quoting and unquote splicing:

```clj
(defn example-2 [ast]
  (let [l10n-key-match [:guard #{:foo :bar}]]
    (match ast
      [`(k ~@l10n-key-match) v lang] {:type k :value v :lang lang}
      [`(k ~@l10n-key-match) v]      {:type k :value v})))
```

However the `defn` expression crashes with:

```
Unexpected error (AssertionError) macroexpanding match at (form-init11111096422056977084.clj:3:5).
Invalid list syntax (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote so.example/k)) l10n-key-match) in (clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote so.example/k)) l10n-key-match)). Valid syntax: [[:default :guard] [:or :default] [:default :only] [:default :seq] [:default :when] [:default :as] [:default :<<] [:default :clojure.core.match/vector]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: unfortunately, you can't pass generated data to this macro when calling it from the function. `(k ~@l10n-key-match)` doesn't get expanded, but rather passed to a `match` macro as is. And it doesn't conform to a source code shape it expects to get.`

Comment: what you can do, is to make this whole `example-2` a macro, so then you could preprocess the shape of source code *before* if gets passed to `match` macro

Comment: @leetwinski Thanks for your comments; they've been useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this what [spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec), that already ships with Clojure, does? You would define your pattern like

```clj
(ns playground.catspec
  (:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as spec]))

(spec/def ::type #{:foo :bar})
(spec/def ::value number?)
(spec/def ::lang #{"en" "sv" "fr"})

(spec/def ::key-value-lang (spec/cat :type ::type
                                     :value ::value
                                     :lang (spec/? ::lang)))
```

We use `spec/def` to define a spec, `spec/cat` to concatenate specs and `spec/?` for a spec that is optional.

Then we use `conform` to parse the tuple:

```clj
(spec/conform ::key-value-lang [:foo 10])
;; => {:type :foo, :value 10}

(spec/conform ::key-value-lang [:bar 20 "en"])
;; => {:type :bar, :value 20, :lang "en"}

(spec/conform ::key-value-lang [:bar 119 "fr"])
;; => {:type :bar, :value 119, :lang "fr"}

(spec/conform ::key-value-lang [119 :foo])
;; => :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid

(spec/conform ::key-value-lang [:bar 119 "uj"])
;; => :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid

(spec/conform ::key-value-lang [:bar])
;; => :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid

(spec/conform ::key-value-lang [:bar 119 "fr" :asdfasdf])
;; => :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid

(spec/conform ::key-value-lang {:a 1 :b 4})
;; => :clojure.spec.alpha/invalid
```

Comment: Amazing. Why didn't I think of that?! Great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't solve the problem with `clojure.core.match`, but you don't really need it for something this simple:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [data      [[:foo 10]
                   [:bar 20 "en"]
                   [:fizz 10]
                   [:buzz 20 "en"]]
        keep-tags #{:foo :bar}
        data-keep (filterv #(contains? keep-tags (first %)) data)
        result    (forv [tuple data-keep]
                    (zipmap [:type :value :lang] tuple))]
    (is= result [{:type :foo, :value 10}
                 {:type :bar, :value 20, :lang "en"}])))
```

You may also be interested in these helper functions:

- [tupelo.core/matches?](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.207/api/tupelo.core#matches?)  A nicer interface to `clojure.core.match`
- [tupelo.core/submatch?](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.207/api/tupelo.core#submatch?)
- [tupelo.core/wild-match?](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.207/api/tupelo.core#wild-match?)
- [tupelo.core/wild-submatch?](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/0.9.207/api/tupelo.core#wild-submatch?)

Comment: I just gave a contrived example in an attempt to remove all the non-essential bits and keep things simple.Point taken nonetheless; will look at your libraries. Thanks.

Comment: Hope it helps! Also, the unit tests show many examples of the 4 functions in action with sample data.